# How do I solve for $x$ in $\ln(x)\ln(x) = 2 +\ln(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve for $x$?

$$\ln(x)\ln(x) = 2 +\ln(x)$$

Comment: This is just a quadratic in $\ln x$. Nothin' tricky.

Comment: I think of it like that too now :)

Comment: Just a quick tip: you now have enough reputation that you can "upvote" as many helpful answers as you'd like, even those you accept. To "upvote", click on the upward-pointing arrow to the left of the answer: when you click, it turns *red*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HINT:

Putting $\ln (x)=y,$ we get

$$y^2-y-2=0.$$

Do you know how to solve a Quadratic Equation?, and we know that

$$\ln (x)=a\iff x=e^a .$$

Comment: So I would get:

y^2 -y -2 = 0
then
(y-2)(y+1)=0
then
ln(x)=2 v ln(x)=-1 (fails)
then
x = e^2

Right?

Comment: edit: ln(x) = -1 doesn't fail, gets us x = 1/e

Comment: @Jones, you got the answer. $\ln(x)$ can assume any real value but as $e^a>0$ for real $a$ and $x$ must be $>0$

Answer (score 5):

$$\ln(x)\ln(x) = 2 + \ln(x) \iff (\ln (x))^2 - \ln (x) - 2 = 0\tag{1}$$

Let $t = \ln x$. Then $(1)$ becomes $$t^2 - t - 2 = (t - 2)(t + 1) = 0\tag{2}$$

So, $$t = \ln x = 2 \implies x = e^2\;\text{ or }\; t = \ln x = -1 \implies x = e^{-1} = \frac 1e$$

Comment: Good morning! Off to the gym. Needs another TU +1